# Registration page of opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I want to edit my register.tpl file of registration process of my opencart page.
I just want to keep the email, password and confirm password fields. When I remove all other fields including first name, last name, address etc and only leave in email, password and confirm password fields, it stops registration.  How can I make it continue registration with only 3 fields and also agree to the terms check box I have to keep.

This is the register.tpl file

```
<div id="content"><?php echo $content_top; ?>

      <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
      <p><?php echo $text_account_already; ?></p>
      <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h2><?php echo $text_your_details; ?></h2>
        <div class="content">
          <table class="form">
            <tr>
              <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_firstname; ?></td>
              <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_firstname) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_firstname; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_lastname; ?></td>
              <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_lastname) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_lastname; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_email; ?></td>
              <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_email) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_email; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_telephone; ?></td>
              <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="telephone" value="<?php echo $telephone; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_telephone) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_telephone; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $entry_fax; ?></td>
              <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="fax" value="<?php echo $fax; ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <h2><?php echo $text_your_address; ?></h2>
        <div class="content">
          <table class="form">
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $entry_company; ?></td>
              <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="company" value="<?php echo $company; ?>" /></td>
            </tr>        
            <tr style="display: <?php echo (count($customer_groups) > 1 ? 'table-row' : 'none'); ?>;">
              <td><?php echo $entry_customer_group; ?></td>
              <td><?php foreach ($customer_groups as $customer_group) { ?>
                <?php if ($customer_group['customer_group_id'] == $customer_group_id) { ?>
                <input type="radio" name="customer_group_id" value="<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>" id="customer_group_id<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>" checked="checked" />
                <label for="customer_group_id<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>"><?php echo $customer_group['name']; ?></label>
                <br />
                <?php } else { ?>
                <input type="radio" name="customer_group_id" value="<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>" id="customer_group_id<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>" />
                <label for="customer_group_id<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>"><?php echo $customer_group['name']; ?></label>
                <br />
                <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>      
            <tr id="company-id-display">
              <td><span id="company-id-required" class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_company_id; ?></td>
              <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="company_id" value="<?php echo $company_id; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_company_id) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_company_id; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="tax-id-display">
              <td><span id="tax-id-required" class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_tax_id; ?></td>
              <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="tax_id" value="<?php echo $tax_id; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_tax_id) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_tax_id; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_address_1; ?></td>
              <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="address_1" value="<?php echo $address_1; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_address_1) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_address_1; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $entry_address_2; ?></td>
              <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="address_2" value="<?php echo $address_2; ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_city; ?></td>
              <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $city; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_city) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_city; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span id="postcode-required" class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_postcode; ?></td>
              <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $postcode; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_postcode) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_postcode; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_country; ?></td>
              <td><select class="form-control" name="country_id">
                  <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
                  <?php foreach ($countries as $country) { ?>
                  <?php if ($country['country_id'] == $country_id) { ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $country['name']; ?></option>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id']; ?>"><?php echo $country['name']; ?></option>
                  <?php } ?>
                  <?php } ?>
                </select>
                <?php if ($error_country) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_country; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_zone; ?></td>
              <td><select class="form-control" name="zone_id">
                </select>
                <?php if ($error_zone) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_zone; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <h2><?php echo $text_your_password; ?></h2>
        <div class="content">
          <table class="form">
            <tr>
              <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_password; ?></td>
              <td><input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_password) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_password; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_confirm; ?></td>
              <td><input class="form-control" type="password" name="confirm" value="<?php echo $confirm; ?>" />
                <?php if ($error_confirm) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_confirm; ?></span>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <h2><?php echo $text_newsletter; ?></h2>
        <div class="content">
          <table class="form">
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $entry_newsletter; ?></td>
              <td><?php if ($newsletter) { ?>
                <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="1" checked="checked" />
                <?php echo $text_yes; ?>
                <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="0" />
                <?php echo $text_no; ?>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="1" />
                <?php echo $text_yes; ?>
                <input type="radio" name="newsletter" value="0" checked="checked" />
                <?php echo $text_no; ?>
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <?php if ($text_agree) { ?>
        <div class="buttons">
          <div class="right"><?php echo $text_agree; ?>
            <?php if ($agree) { ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1" checked="checked" />
            <?php } else { ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1" />
            <?php } ?>
            <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_continue; ?>" class="button" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="buttons">
          <div class="right">
            <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_continue; ?>" class="button" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
      </form>
      <?php echo $content_bottom; ?></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to catalog/controller/account/register.php (controller) and into the function validate(). Remove the unnecessary fields. Then remove the fields from your tpl. In this way, you will be able to proceed with only three fields.

Comment: sir could you please tell me how to call register.tpl fle into header as <?php echo $register ?> as in other files in opencart header file is called as <?php echo $header ?> and the above problem is solved.

Comment: You will have to write this code in to your header controller.

`$data['register'] = $this->load->controller('account/register);`

This will automatically call the register controller in your header controller. You can see admin/controller/common/dashboard.php for example too.

Comment: Vote up if you find this answer helpful :)

Comment: Sir could you please explain that where the above code should be inserted in header.php file of controller as there is no any dashboard.php file for reference.

Comment: the dashboard.php file is in admin panel => ROOT/admin/controller/common/dashboard.php

Comment: One more this Sir after define this code in header.php file it is given error that is "undefined method Loader::controller() in C:\wamp\www\1\catalog\controller\common\header.php on line 33" So please tell me how to fix this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80737/discussion-between-ali-zia-and-sandal).